# GNUStep base make error

Tags: macos, gnu-make, gnustep

I am installing GNUSTEP on MAC OS X. I am using gnu c compiler(5.1). Following the steps from README.Darwin which is present in the gnu package.
Everything went fine until the make step for gnu base.

I am getting the following errors

```
    
    This is gnustep-make 2.6.7. Type 'gnumake print-gnustep-make-help' for help.
```

```
Making all in Source ...
rm -f dynamic-load.h
cp simple-load.h dynamic-load.h

/usr/local/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/mkinstalldirs .
mv ../Headers/GNUstepBase/config.h .
touch ./config.h
/usr/local/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/mkinstalldirs ./GNUstepBase
mv ../Headers/GNUstepBase/GSConfig.h ./GNUstepBase
touch ./GNUstepBase/GSConfig.h
Making all in ObjectiveC2 ...
Making all for subproject ObjectiveC2...

Compiling file runtime.c ...
In file included from runtime.c:35:0:
/usr/local/include/objc/objc-api.h:355:1: error: unknown type name          ‘retval_t’
retval_t objc_msg_sendv(id, SEL, arglist_t);
/usr/local/include/objc/objc-api.h:355:34: error: unknown type name  ‘arglist_t’
retval_t objc_msg_sendv(id, SEL, arglist_t);

/usr/local/include/objc/objc-api.h:433:33: error: unknown type name     ‘MetaClass’

Method_t class_get_class_method(MetaClass _class, SEL aSel);

/usr/local/include/objc/objc-api.h: In function ‘class_get_class_name’:
/usr/local/include/objc/objc-api.h:469:10: error: dereferencing pointer     to incomplete type ‘struct objc_class’
return CLS_ISCLASS(_class)?_class->name:((_class==Nil)?"Nil":0);
/usr/local/include/objc/objc-api.h: At top level:
/usr/local/include/objc/objc-api.h:478:15: error: unknown type name ‘   MetaClass’
static inline MetaClass
/usr/local/include/objc/objc-api.h: In function    ‘object_get_class_name’:
/usr/local/include/objc/objc-api.h:562:42: error: dereferencing pointer   to incomplete type ‘struct objc_class’

                      :((Class)object)->name)

/usr/local/include/objc/objc-api.h: At top level:
/usr/local/include/objc/objc-api.h:566:15: error: unknown type name  ‘MetaClass’
static inline MetaClass
In file included from runtime.c:37:0:
/usr/local/include/objc/encoding.h:71:6: error: unknown type name    ‘arglist_t’
arglist_t argframe, 
/usr/local/include/objc/encoding.h:73:33: error: unknown type name   ‘arglist_t’
char *method_get_next_argument (arglist_t argframe, 
/usr/local/include/objc/encoding.h:76:11: error: unknown type name    ‘arglist_t’ arglist_t argframe,
runtime.c: In function ‘class_getInstanceMethodNonrecursive’:

runtime.c:109:28: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type  ‘struct objc_class’

   for (methods = aClass->methods;

runtime.c:118:31: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type  ‘const struct objc_selector’
if (method->method_name->sel_id == aSelector->sel_id)
runtime.c:118:52: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type   ‘const struct objc_selector’
if (method->method_name->sel_id == aSelector->sel_id)
runtime.c: In function ‘class_addProtocol’:
runtime.c:252:22: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-   Wincompatible-pointer-types]

protocols->list[0] = protocol;
runtime.c: In function ‘objc_allocateClassPair’:
runtime.c:1021:31: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete   type ‘struct objc_class’
newClass = calloc(1, sizeof(struct objc_class) + extraBytes);
runtime.c:1029:32: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete   type ‘struct objc_class’
metaClass = calloc(1, sizeof(struct objc_class));
runtime.c:1037:37: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete   type ‘struct objc_class’

metaClass->instance_size = sizeof(struct objc_class);
runtime.c: In function ‘objc_allocateMetaClass’:
runtime.c:1055:38: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete    type ‘struct objc_class’

Class metaClass = calloc(1, sizeof(struct objc_class) + extraBytes);

runtime.c:1063:37: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete    type ‘struct objc_class’

metaClass->instance_size = sizeof(struct objc_class);
runtime.c: In function ‘object_getIndexedIvars’:
runtime.c:1073:38: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete         type ‘struct objc_class’

   return ((char *) obj) + sizeof(struct objc_class);

runtime.c: In function ‘objc_getProtocol’:
runtime.c:1179:35: error: ‘GNU_Protocol {aka struct objc_object_gnu}’   has no member named ‘protocol_name’

    if (strcmp(pcllist->list[i]->protocol_name, name) == 0)

runtime.c: In function ‘protocol_conformsToProtocol’:
runtime.c:1202:39: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type    ‘Protocol {aka struct objc_protocol}’
```

struct objc_protocol_list *list = p1->protocol_list;

```
runtime.c:1216:28: error: ‘GNU_Protocol {aka struct objc_object_gnu}’     has no member named ‘protocol_name’

if (strcmp(list->list[i]->protocol_name, p2->protocol_name) == 0)

runtime.c: In function ‘sel_isEqual’:
runtime.c:1419:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sel_eq’    [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

return sel_eq(sel1, sel2) ? YES : NO;
runtime.c: In function ‘class_getClassMethod’:
runtime.c:392:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-   Wreturn-type]

}

runtime.c: In function ‘class_getInstanceSize’:
runtime.c:409:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-  Wreturn-type]

}
runtime.c: In function ‘class_getIvarLayout’:
runtime.c:481:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-    Wreturn-type]

}runtime.c: In function ‘class_getSuperclass’:

runtime.c:544:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-   Wreturn-type]

}
runtime.c: In function ‘objc_getMetaClass’:
runtime.c:875:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-   Wreturn-type]

}
runtime.c: In function ‘object_getIndexedIvars’:
runtime.c:1076:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-    Wreturn-type]

}
gnumake[4]: *** [obj/ObjectiveC2.obj/runtime.c.o] Error 1
gnumake[3]: *** [internal-subproject-all_] Error 2
gnumake[2]: *** [ObjectiveC2.all.subproject.variables] Error 2
gnumake[1]: *** [internal-all] Error 2
make: *** [internal-all] Error 2
```

Comment: Any advice on this issue would be of great help.Thanks in advance

Comment: You are bringing coals to Newcastle!  Why install a second-rate Objective-C implementation on a platform with a first class one, which is ready to use by simply installing Xcode?

Comment: Hi I am working on a project that needs gnustep environment. It is just not for objective c implementation.